# how to collect admin templates file in django

Tags: django, templates

I just created a `STATIC_ROOT` and collected all the static files, like css, js, fonts. etc. But I need to see some django admin templates as well and I would like to collect them into a folder. Is there anyway to do that? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes go to your site packages directory then to django then contrib then admin and then templates. There you will find all the templates.  Copy the templates you want to edit and save it in your's templates folder and inside admib folder.

Comment: somehow I don't see add user template... hm, thank you anyway.