# How can I customize Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm a PHP developer, now I'm learning Python and building web site with Django. The biggest question for me is that I want customize the admin template at all, is there any way? Or is it right to override it with custom app? What you can suggest?

Comment: For the look and feel, look at Django Suit. It is very nice, and easy to install. http://djangosuit.com/

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, first you have to import your admin templates, read this [how to collect admin templates file in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898697/how-to-collect-admin-templates-file-in-Django) . Also you have to collect admin static typing manage.py collectstatic, then you can modify your static and your templates. Your question is too broad, so let me know if you want to know more

Comment: collect admin templates and statics you mean i must copy them manually to my project templates/admin and static/admin folders ?.And after change them ?

Comment: Yes, but static files you can do it automatically typing manage.py collect static

Comment: thanks, also i have questions about middlewares in django , please can you provide some good documentation for django ?

Comment: Django is well documented you can search in google and it will show you the docs with the information you need. Don't forget voteup